# I invert to 'if' statement and the code don't works

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a JSON file where the objects are in this form:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1568811686,
  "attachments": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "external_context": {
            "url": "https://media2.giphy.com/media/ce1ARlVo9jPdhwbOKL/v1.Y2lkPTEyMGMwMTQ3NTRjOGMwMjc2MTU2NzE5NmRiODQ5NzY5MTEyN2JmMmZmZTMwNjg3Mg/giphy-downsized.gif"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "title": "Name Surname ha commentato il post di Name Surname."
},
```

but not everyone has the key 'url'. I'm tring to add this objects on a neo4j db using py2neo and I wrote the function below to do it:

```
    for comment in comments['comments']:

      if 'data' in comment:
         group = ''
          for d in comment['data']:
              comment = d['comment']['comment'].encode('latin1')
               if 'group' in d['comment']:
                  group = d['comment']['group'].encode('latin1')

          if group == '':
            node = Node('Comment', timestamp=timestamp, title=title, comment=comment_text)
          else:
            node = Node('Comment', timestamp=timestamp, title=title, comment=comment_text, group=group)

        graph.create(node)

    if 'attachments' in comment:
        for attachments in comment['attachments']:
            for d in attachments['data']:
                if 'external_context' in d:
                    url = d['external_context']['url']
                    print url
```

For testing, I'm just printing the **url** variable, but here I have some troubles, in fact if I run this code the second ***if*** (*if 'attachments' in comment:* )
is not executed, but if I invert the two if statement the code is correctly execute. Why?

Comment: As it says in the coding guidelines, we need (1) the shortest code necessary to illustrate the problem, and (2) examples of the actual and expected output.  What defines correct execution?  What is the value of `comment` at the second `if`, and how does it not match your expectations?

Comment: @Prune sorry, I wanted to be as detailed as possible. I modified the code to make it shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mutate the variable `comment` inside the loop while iterating on it. This usually cause nasy bugs and considered as forbidden.

```
for d in comment['data']:
            comment = d['comment']['comment']
```

Just change the comment inside the loop to something else.